# Update Query is being skipped in if statement vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I don't now why the method is being skipped in the if statement Can anybody help me with this problem?

here's the update sql query

```
    Public Sub Edituser()
   conn()
   dbconn.Open()
    sql = "UPDATE player SET First Name=@1 Last Name=@2, Gender=@3, Date of Birth=@4, Civil Status=@5, Nationality=@6, Address=@7, Status=@8 WHERE ID = " + TextBox8.Text + ""
    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@1", TextBox1.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@2", TextBox2.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@3", TextBox9.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@4", TextBox3.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@5", TextBox4.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@6", TextBox5.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@7", TextBox6.Text))
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@8", TextBox7.Text))
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        dbread.Close()
        MsgBox("Successfully updated!")
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        dbconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and here's the if statement

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Or TextBox6.Text = "" Or TextBox7.Text = "" Or TextBox9.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please complete all the fields")
    Else
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Edit the information?", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.OK Then


            Edituser()

            MsgBox(" Player information Updated!")
            Me.Close()
            Player.Show()
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never put an user input in your query by concatenation. It makes it vulnerable for sql injection. You were on the right track by using the parameters in the set part.

Comment: you should learn how to use the debugger. if your if statement is entered it will call the 'EditUser()' method, as is posted below  in Rahuls answer your problem seems to be with syntax in your 'EditUser()' method. not the if statement calling the method.

Comment: at the very least display ex.Message to a MessageBox or Debug.Writeline() so that you can see what is wrong with your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is syntactically wrong as it's missing `,` and proper quoting for column names as pointed below

```
sql = "UPDATE player SET `First Name`=@1, `Last Name`=@2, Gender=@3, `Date of Birth`=@4,
```

Comment: I did all the comments and answer so I got this error "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

Answer (score 0):

sub is called edituser, you are calling editplayer?

ok. you are squashing the error in the empty catch block. most likely you are hitting a sql error passing the date parameter as a string.

you would need to remove the try catch to get a look at the error message, or output it to console/msgbox.

also what @Rahul says also is correct. possibly combination of both.